# allow request permission in runtime not working

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-maps

I have follow the tutorial in this link to be able to allow  request permission in runtime : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

and it is not working, I copy the same code but with different permission "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

my code as following

in onCreate method of activity

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

        DialogUtils.showDialogMessage(this, getString(R.string.error),
                getString(R.string.error_location_permission_not_granted), getString(R.string.ok), getString(R.string.cancel), new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    /*ContextCompat.requestPermissions(ItemDetailsActivity2.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MAP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);*/
                    }
                }, null);

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MAP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

and this is the call back method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MAP_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                initalizeMap();
            } else {

                DialogUtils.showDialogMessage(this, getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.error_location_permission_not_granted), getString(R.string.ok), null);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my build configuration

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 15
```

can anyone please tell me what is going wrong with me ?

**EDIT**

when I change the targetSdkVersion to 23 in both manifest and gradle file, and run my app it gives me the following screen, and when I press allow, give me black screen for long time, and do nothing else

can you please tell me what is the problem now ?

[image]

Comment: yes, I am running on device with android version 6.0.1

Answer (score 2):

In the future, please explain in detail what "it is not working" means.

In this case, I am going to guess that "it is not working" means "the dialog for the user to grant permission is not appearing". That is because your `targetSdkVersion` is set to `15`, not `23` or higher. By having a `targetSdkVersion` of `15`, you are saying that you want the legacy permission support, where the user has to agree to all permissions at install time, including ones with a `dangerous` `protectionLevel`.

Comment: so do you suggest that I change the targetSdkVersion to 23 ??

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail: I do not know why you have it set to 15. If you want runtime permissions to work, you will need to raise it to at least 23. However, there may be other changes that you need to make to your code once you do that. You will need to review the JavaDocs for [the `VERSION_CODES` between 16 and 23](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) to see what else you might need to modify.

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail: Presumably, your current problems are tied into your `initializeMap()` method. You will need to debug that yourself (e.g., step through the code with the debugger). If you have further concerns, ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] for your new problem.